# A priest died inside the temple beside the valmiki sage idol

Tags: rituals, temple

My question is  nearly about 24 years ago a priest died inside the temple beside an idol of sage shri valmiki rishi and after the death of the sage the temple was open and alternatively pooja rituals were going on now people are saying that the idol got ruined with negative energy. Please let us know that is it mandatory to remove the old idol and replace a new one Or we can just purify it with another method?

Comment: Well personally I don't think there should be any connection between the two coz we do know and say that God is everywhere and as such if anyone dies anywhere do we replace that entity every time? For instance a hospital bed where many die same day but we don't alter anything..no? But yes we can follow some purification procedure for sure.

Comment: Not much positive energy in the murthi to start if you think it was ruined by a death near to it. If anything, it purified the soul of the person that died near to it. It needs no purification, perhaps those that think it does need purification....

Comment: people who are in favor to remove the idol are saying that by agama shastra the old idol should be removed and new one to be replaced kindly please suggest is any shastra really say this or its a myth.